# Using Javascript on UIWebView to get all of a particular div class

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to put the results of all the div classes named "thumb" of a finished UIWebView into a string, but I have no idea why NSLog is showing only the first div class thumb (should be 37 different instances of "thumb")

I appreciate your help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.thewebsite.com"]]];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{   
    if (!webView.isLoading)
    {
        NSString *test = @"function f()"
        "{"
            "var theThumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');"
            "for(var i=0; i < theThumbs.length; i++)"
            "{"
                "return(theThumbs[i].innerHTML);"
            "}"
        "}f()";

        NSString *input = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:test];

        NSLog(@"String is: %@", input);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your for loop you call "return" so you're returning from the function on first run. I think you want to append to a var and return that at the end, outside the for loop

Comment: Can you elaborate further? I'm not very good with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
  'return(theThumbs[i].innerHTML);'
```

you are returning from the function on very first iteration. It doesn't loop through the loop each time. You need to create a variable to hold the values.

```
 "var theThumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');"
 "var someString = '';"
        "for(var i=0; i < theThumbs.length; i++)"
        "{"
            "someString +=(theThumbs[i].innerHTML);"
        "}"
"return someString;"
```